# Guice : How to customize the bindings of a third-party Module?

Tags: java, guice

Let's say I have a `ThirPartyModule` third-party Module which binds lots of components that I can then use in my application :

```
Injector guice = Guice.createInjector(new MyAppModule(), new ThirPartyModule());
```

If I want to modify the implementation classes used for some bindings in that Module, what is the best approach?

For example, let's say `ThirPartyModule` performs that binding :

```
bind(WidgetInterface.class).to(DefaultWidgeImpl.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
```

and I want to be able to change the `DefaultWidgeImpl` class for `MyWidgetImpl` class. I know I could use an overriding Module, and simply rebind the `WidgetInterface` key. But what if `ThirPartyModule` binds ***a lot*** of things using that same *Widget implementation*? I may not want to have to rebind each of them!

So I'm trying to find the best solution to be able to specify the implementation class to use, without having the rebind all the components depending on it.

I guess `ThirPartyModule` could first create a getter method for the implementation class :

```
bind(WidgetInterface.class).to(getWidgetImpClass()).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);

protected Class<? extends WidgetInterface> getWidgetImpClass() {
    return DefaultWidgeImpl.class;
}
```

and then the application could override the `getWidgetImpClass()` method :

```
Injector guice = Guice.createInjector(new MyAppModule(), new ThirPartyModule() {
    @Override
    protected Class<? extends WidgetInterface> getWidgetImpClass() {
        return MyWidgetImpl.class;
    }   
});
```

I also though about passing the implementation class to the constructor of the Module :

```
Injector guice = Guice.createInjector(new MyAppModule(), new ThirPartyModule(MyWidgetImpl.class));
```

I'd like to know if there is an accepted pattern to customize such third-party Modules? Let's say I *can* ask the Modules to be written in a specific way if it helps them to be customizable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
public class ThirdPartyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        // CoolWidget --
        //              \
        //               > WidgetInterface -> DefaultWidgetImpl
        //              /
        // AwesomeWidget

        OptionalBinder.newOptionalBinder(binder(), WidgetInterface.class)
                .setDefault()
                .to(DefaultWidgetImpl.class);

        bind(CoolWidget.class).to(WidgetInterface.class);
        bind(AwesomeWidget.class).to(WidgetInterface.class);
        // etc.
    }
}

public class MyAppModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        OptionalBinder.newOptionalBinder(binder(), WidgetInterface.class)
                .setBinding()
                .to(CustomWidgetImpl.class);
    }
}
```

By making all the bindings go indirectly through the `WidgetInterface` key, you only need to override that one binding.

Comment: Wow, I have to admit I didn't even know `OptionalBinder`, it's going to be handy indeed... Thanks!

Comment: I don't think being a singleton has anything to do with `@Named("default")`.  If `CustomWidgetImpl` has to be a singleton then mark it with `@Singleton` or do `.in(Singleton.class)`.

Comment: Regardless, you can probably do without `@Named("default")`.  It would just be `{CoolWidget, AwesomeWidget} -> WidgetInterface -> DefaultWidgetImpl`.